# Invalid cast from 'Boolean' to 'DateTime'

Tags: vb.net

I keep getting this error

> Invalid cast from 'Boolean' to 'DateTime'

when the codes below try to execute.

I am basically trying to update my auction_item table where the "closedate < todayDate" is met.

This is where the error fires [Dim forupdate As Date = Convert.ToDateTime(closedate < todayDate)]

```
    con.Open()

    CMD = New SqlCommand("SELECT  auction_item_close_date FROM auction_items WHERE (auction_item_status_id = 1)", con)
    DR = CMD.ExecuteReader()
    DR.Read()

    Dim closedate As Date
    closedate = Convert.ToDateTime(DR(0))
    con.Close()

    Dim todayDate As Date = DateAndTime.Today

    Dim forupdate As Date = Convert.ToDateTime(closedate < todayDate)

    con.Open()
    If closedate < todayDate Then
        SQL = "UPDATE auction_items SET auction_item_status_id = 2, auction_item_open_closed = 'closed' WHERE auction_item_close_date = '" & forupdate & "'"
        CMD = New SqlCommand(SQL, con)
        CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()

        con.Close()

    End If
```

Comment: What are you expecting `Dim forupdate As Date = Convert.ToDateTime(closedate < todayDate)` to do?

Comment: Thanks. I am expecting it to look at my auction items table, the auction_item_close_date column in particular and look for where the date the auction is to end (closedate), if it is less than the current date (todayDate) and effect the SQL update whereever the condition is met! Thats what I'm trying to do. Do forgive me as I'm very new to programming! Thanks again for your response!

Comment: This new information actually makes the question quite different. Firstly you don't need to get the closed date out as an initial query. All you need is a single update with a where clause of `WHERE closed_date < @TodaysDate`. @TodaysDate would be the parameter that you pass to the query with today's date in. IF you haven't used parameterised SQL in .net before then I strongly advise you to go look it up since once you get the hang of it it is much easier (and better in other ways) than concatenating strings into your query.

Comment: Note: I'm not adding this as an answer since it doesn't actually answer the question as stated at the moment (which is about casting from boolean to date).

Comment: Okay! I will study more about using parameters in SQL and see if I can resolve this!

Comment: Do come back with a new question if you get stuck again. Hopefully my comment above should help get you where you need to be though. :)

Answer (score 3):

The error is on this line:

```
Dim forupdate As Date = Convert.ToDateTime(closedate < todayDate)
```

`closedate < todayDate` returns `true` or `false` depending on whether `closedate` is before `todayDate`.

That value can not be converted to a `DateTime` and this is what the exception says. Maybe you need to rethink what the line is supposed to do.